# How can I detect overlapping geometries in OpenLayers 6.3.1

Tags: openlayers, intersection, overlapping-features

I'm using OL 6.3.1 and have a need to detect when the geometries of polygons overlap or intersect. Specifically I am trying to do something like this when a user draws a polygon:

```
self.olMap.addInteraction(self.drawInteraction);
self.drawInteraction.on('drawend', function(e){
self.newFeature = e.feature;
var drawnFeatureGeometry = self.newFeature.getGeometry();
var allFeatures = self.displaySource.getFeatures();
for(var i = 0;i < allFeatures.length; i++){
    var thisGeometry = allFeatures[i].getGeometry();
    if(drawnFeatureGeometry intersects with thisGeometry) // pseudoCode here. What can I do?
    {
        self.drawInteraction.abortDrawing();
        self.drawInteraction.source_.clear();
        alert('Features may not overlap. Please try again.');
        break
    }        
}
```

});

I've found examples in previous versions, but those classes seem to have been deprecated.

containsExtent and containsPixel do not meet the use case.

I read the API documentation for Intersects (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_filter_Intersects-Intersects.html) but I couldn't see how it applies.

Any ideas?

Also, abortDrawing() doesn't seem to work as described in the API documentation.

Comment: You would need a third party utility such as turf https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect  You would first need to convert the features to turf features as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/turf.html

Comment: You can have a look at an example of using turf.js to detect intersections here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344068/splitting-a-polygon-by-multiple-linestrings-leaflet-and-turf-js

Comment: Thank you. I saw a couple of examples using turf.js. I was hoping third party libraries wouldn't be necessary, but if that's the best or only way forward I'll try turf.js. Thank you again.

Comment: My link above to an example of using turf.js to detect intersections is mistakenly for Leaflet. Here is the one for OpenLayers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339622/splitting-feature-in-openlayers-5/340974#340974

Comment: Thanks for the tip on turf.js. I am now detecting intersections just fine. The problem I continue to see is once the intersection is detected I can't seem to prevent the sketch from being added to the vector source. I have tried using the abortDraw() function, as well as drawInteraction.setActive('false'). In all cases the sketch is added to the vector source.