# OpenLayers & JSTS - Unable to convert Polygon using OL3Parser

Tags: openlayers, parse, jsts

In a project that I am working on I need to split up a feature. In order to do so I have found a guided explanation online on how to achieve this: [Explanation](https://medium.com/random-gis-talks/split-a-polygon-by-line-in-openlayers-95a9cc834a16).

At some point you need to convert the Polygon to a JSTS object using the OL3Parser. But I keep on getting the following error: `Uncaught IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)`.

I have speciale used the same Feature, Polygon and Coordinates used as in the example to minimize the differences between my project and the example.

But I still keep on getting this error. I have also added `parser.inject(Point, LineString, Polygon)`. Because before I added this I got a different error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Point' of undefined`. But after some research online I have found a fix for this problem: [Link to the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146569/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-point-of-undefined-openlayers-3-jsts).

```
    let polygon = new Feature({
      geometry: new Polygon([
        [
          [-10852646.620625805, 3906819.5017894786],
          [-10797367.365502242, 3950847.234747086],
          [-10691456.211645748, 3911711.47159973],
          [-10687298.044771587, 3848605.062913627],
          [-10777554.891503, 3804332.7398631293],
          [-10864387.34630427, 3834907.5511772],
          [-10852646.620625805, 3906819.5017894786],
        ],
      ]),
    });

    let parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
    parser.inject(Point, LineString, Polygon);

    let a = parser.read(polygon.getGeometry());
```

I have noticed that Geometry types are slightly different between my project and the example project. When I `console.log` both Geometries in my project it is of type 'Polygon' and in the example project it is of type 'e'.

My project:

[image: My Project geometry]

Example project:

[image: Example project geometry]

Here I also include the objects of both of the Geometry objects in both projects. Here I have noticed that the `orientedFlatCoordinates_` is empty in my project:

My project:

```
{
  "disposed": false,
  "pendingRemovals_": null,
  "dispatching_": null,
  "listeners_": {
    "change": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "revision_": 1,
  "ol_uid": "2977",
  "values_": null,
  "extent_": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ],
  "extentRevision_": -1,
  "simplifiedGeometryMaxMinSquaredTolerance": 0,
  "simplifiedGeometryRevision": 0,
  "layout": "XY",
  "stride": 2,
  "flatCoordinates": [
    -10852646.620625805,
    3906819.5017894786,
    -10797367.365502242,
    3950847.234747086,
    -10691456.211645748,
    3911711.47159973,
    -10687298.044771587,
    3848605.062913627,
    -10777554.891503,
    3804332.7398631293,
    -10864387.34630427,
    3834907.5511772,
    -10852646.620625805,
    3906819.5017894786
  ],
  "ends_": [
    14
  ],
  "flatInteriorPointRevision_": -1,
  "flatInteriorPoint_": null,
  "maxDelta_": -1,
  "maxDeltaRevision_": -1,
  "orientedRevision_": -1,
  "orientedFlatCoordinates_": null
}
```

Example project:

```
{
  "disposed": false,
  "pendingRemovals_": null,
  "dispatching_": null,
  "listeners_": {
    "change": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "revision_": 1,
  "ol_uid": "24",
  "values_": null,
  "extent_": [
    -10864387.34630427,
    3804332.7398631293,
    -10687298.044771587,
    3950847.234747086
  ],
  "extentRevision_": 1,
  "simplifiedGeometryMaxMinSquaredTolerance": 5842.619293068835,
  "simplifiedGeometryRevision": 1,
  "layout": "XY",
  "stride": 2,
  "flatCoordinates": [
    -10852646.620625805,
    3906819.5017894786,
    -10797367.365502242,
    3950847.234747086,
    -10691456.211645748,
    3911711.47159973,
    -10687298.044771587,
    3848605.062913627,
    -10777554.891503,
    3804332.7398631293,
    -10864387.34630427,
    3834907.5511772,
    -10852646.620625805,
    3906819.5017894786
  ],
  "ends_": [
    14
  ],
  "flatInteriorPointRevision_": -1,
  "flatInteriorPoint_": null,
  "maxDelta_": -1,
  "maxDeltaRevision_": -1,
  "orientedRevision_": 1,
  "orientedFlatCoordinates_": [
    -10852646.620625805,
    3906819.5017894786,
    -10797367.365502242,
    3950847.234747086,
    -10691456.211645748,
    3911711.47159973,
    -10687298.044771587,
    3848605.062913627,
    -10777554.891503,
    3804332.7398631293,
    -10864387.34630427,
    3834907.5511772,
    -10852646.620625805,
    3906819.5017894786
  ]
}
```

Comment: The inject parameters must be passed in the specified order http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/1.6.1/doc/org_locationtech_jts_io_OL3Parser.js.html#line29

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your comment. I have viewed the link and it states that `parser.inject(Point, LineString, Polygon)` is in line with the given order of the link. `inject(Point, LineString, LinearRing, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, GeometryCollection)`

Comment: Or should I also add `LinearRing` when I am not parsing any of these objects?

Comment: The JSTS code checks for each geometry type in the sequence so you will need to include all of them up to at least Polygon

Comment: @Mike Thank you very much for the suggestions! This was indeed the problem. If you want you can answer the question and I will accept it as being solved.

Comment: You might find useful polygon splitting function based on turf.js library, described in the answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344068/splitting-a-polygon-by-multiple-linestrings-leaflet-and-turf-js/344277#344277. It's used in Leaflet environment, but could easily be used for OpenLayers.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks for the tip! I will look into that. Do you prefer that approach to the one specified in the example I found?

Comment: That's up to you to decide what's simpler for you and what works best for you. I just find JSTS too complex and complicated for my needs. turf.js is much simpler and easier to handle, but on the other hand more limited than JSTS.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks for leading me in the right direction!